# What happens when my Firestore reading limit expires?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

What happens when my reading limit expires in firestore? Am I losing contact or do I get warning messages on every snapshot?

And for example, how can I give the message 'We're dealing with a problem now' when I lose the connection in flutter (i think i should add timeout etc CircularProgressIndicator and show message?)
simply streambuilder is doing my job right now:

```
 child:  StreamBuilder(
        stream:Firestore.instance.collection('file').orderBy('numbers').snapshots(),
    builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
      if(!snapshot.hasData) {return Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator());}
      else {return gridView(snapshot.data.documents);},)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've reached your read quota for Firestore, read operations that require data from the server will start failing. In most cases an error will be raised, which you can catch in your code (although I don't know what exact error will show up in Flutter).

Comment: Thank you for the answer so i have a few more questions. The failure of new readings doesn't affect those already cached right? (is stream builder works this way?) and so how can I find out which error is it? I'm gonna have to fill out my own quota and make it simultaneous or something eeeh

Comment: I don''t think so, because if the connection to firestore was successfull it will try to retrieve the documents from server only, since .getDocuments() and .snapshot() only use cache if there's no internet connection.